# GLASSFISH deployment [never ends]

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish

So I am deploying my REST webservice... Normally I always had it locally hosted on my own computer, but now I am done with the application so I want to host it for real, yet I am stuck deploying it, it keeps on saying: deploying...

So locally it works, but now I've added a remote server and I've tested it with a blanco webservice, and that does work.

Does anyone know what is going on? Because there is no error at all...

BTW I have tested to deploy it with the admin site thing, the [website]:4848 > application > deploy > [add war] --- but that crashes as well... after like 30 seconds of nothing, the webpage says: The connection was reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clue what it is, but if anyone else sees this in the future, where they cannot deploy their webservice, because it takes forever, here's the solution:

1. Copy your .war that you have build onto the server
2. ./asadmin deploy (For glassfish 4.1, this is located in the [main directory]/bin)
3. Fill in all information needed
4. That's it :) I don't like it either, but at least it's a way to deploy!